# Which is more likely to give the bigger performance boost, i5 to i7 or HDD to SSD?

Tags: laptop, memory, hard-disk

This might be comparing apples to oranges, but I know that one of these most likely gives a user a greater performance gain.

If given the chance to only have one: 
Which is more likely to give the bigger performance boost, i5 to i7 or HDD to SSD?

Comment: Performance boost in terms of..?

Comment: It depends entirely on what you're trying to do.  For example, if you're raytracing small scenes, the extra clock speed of an i7 will give you a boost, but an SSD will do nothing.  Conversely, if you're running an IO-heavy database server, the CPU change will do nothing, but switching to an SSD will give an unbelievable performance boost.

Answer (score 2):

- CPU upgrade should raise your PC performance in CPU dependent apllications and games.
- HDD to SSD upgrade will significantly raise speed of opening/closing OS, running applications or copying files.

I would say that CPU upgrade will give bigger performance boost but HDD->SSD upgrade will reduce times of everyday operations like booting system, copying files, running applications. In my opinion SSD choice is better because difference will be more "visible" after changing HDD to SSD than i5 to i7.